# jquery fileupload input box doubling up

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

People with experience using BlueImp's Jquery FileUpload plugin only please

using Razor/C#/MVC/Blueimp's Jquery FileUpload, the jqueryUI version

So I wanted an image to be my 'select file' button. I wrapped the input in a `<span class="fileinput-button">` and instead of using a button element, I use an img element.  It seems to work, pulls up the file selection dialogue, sets the value of the input just fine.  So I size the input to match the image size.  All good so far.

I notice that the pointer is acting funny so I inspect the element and find that there are actually two input boxes on top each other.  One is perfect, right over the img...but the second is something like 139px by 33px and sits over the image as well (top-left aligned) but

I used inspect-element, highlighted each input and they both lead to the same exact spot in the code...that's what I can't figure out, I inspect element, highlight the 139px input and it takes me here to the 54px element...they both lead here.

```
<span class="fileinput-button">
  <img class="clickable" src="~/Images/section/section49.png" width="54" height="54">
  <input type="file" name="file" value="" style="height:54px; width: 54px;">
</span>
```

Has anyone else ran across this?

I know this isn't much to go on but the code is all pretty straight-forward.  The only other info I can think of to add is 1. the span is inside a table cell, and 2. all of this is in a modal dialogue...don't think that matters tho...let me know if any extra info is needed for clarity.

thanks

(just to help visualize, the image below is Chrome highlighting said 139px wide element...clicking on it leads to the above 54px wide element. I've never seen element inspector act this way.  There is no CSS in the list that would affect this perhaps is something to do with the way the blueimp plugin behaves?)

[image: highlight reveals a second input]

Comment: please check on the dom inspector if you still has this `<input type="file" name="file" value="" style="height:54px; width: 54px;">`, take note if it has the same style that you have coded..

Comment: yep, that's the weird part...highlighting the 139px input leads to the 54x54 input element...they both lead to that one input element

Comment: so you can still see the exact `style="height:54px; width: 54px;"` in the dom inspector?

Comment: yes...and there's more, I have several other clickable images on the same page.  I've spanned each one, they each have their own input type=file (unique names for each) and in every case and second input element is getting written.  same 139x32 for them all

Comment: in the dom inspector, each 139x32 input element leads to its repective input element of the differing size if that makes sense.  It all works and I'm tempted to let it go but the 139 is spilling over and causing the upload hotspot to trigger when the mouse is not on the image

Comment: well here's something interesting, the above is all taking place in Chrome...in firefox it acts precisely as intended, no 139px input box exists

Comment: well, you can give `.fileinput-button` the intended height and width and make it overflow hidden...

Comment: yea...would still have two but even worse, would still have an unsolved mystery. :) currently playing around with replacing the img element with a button like blueimp's example, size the button 54x54, background-image with the image, click-event jquery to set form data and post :)  thanks for your input, what a weird issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did instead:

did away with trying to use JQueryFileUpload plugin's "fileinput-button" span multiple times in a modal

instead I put a class="clickable" on each image, added a data- attribute with the extra info I needed.  Then attached a click event to each "clickable" class and manually fired the plugin's input...from there, JQueryFileUpload plugin takes over and acts as normal.

In the plugin's form section, looks as it would normally

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" value=""/>
```

A button opens the modal which contains multiple slots, user clicks the image (represents a slot to which the files will be uploaded).

```
<img class="clickable" data-asset-type="@AssetType.Slot23" src=...etc
```

Because the modal is rendered from the page that the plugin is also in, I can just use jquery to toss the info over to the plugin and let it handle things as normal

```
$(".clickable").click(function () {
        var assetType = $(this).attr('data-asset-type');
        $('input[name="AssetType"]').val(assetType); // the hidden field
        $('#modal-container').fadeOut(300);
        $('input#file').click();
        return false;
    });
```

The result is a modal window with multiple file upload buttons all sending back to one spot with the data acquired from the modal window. And once the user selects a file, JQFileUpload acts as normal, showing the file in the queue and all the nice extras that plugin offers.